# Fatal error, unable to load the Linking Module

Tags: content-delivery, dynamic-linking

We are Upgrading CD 8.5 to 9.1. we are Updated All the roles/configs as per New version. We are Created New Broker/discovery Databases and Executed all the required scripts for New version.

we are getting below error while launching the website. can you help us why it's getting error while resolving URL with Component TcmID.

ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Linking.Impl.ComponentLinkImpl.GetLink] - Exception occurred
EXCEPTION:
**Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query** ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> **Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the Linking Module"}}**
at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters) at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri) at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.b__1()
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy)
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception e, Int32 statusCode) at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.b__0()
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount) at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Linking.AbstractLink.DoExecuteFunc(ODataV4ClientFunction func)
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy)
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Linking.AbstractLink.ExecuteFunc(ODataV4ClientFunction func)
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Linking.Impl.ComponentLinkImpl.GetLink(String sourcePageURI, String targetComponentURI, String excludeTemplateURI, String linkTagAttributes, String linkText, Boolean showTextOnFail, Boolean showAnchor)